# What is the difference between return and console.log()

Tags: javascript, function, fizzbuzz

I get different outputs when I use console.log() in my function vs when I use the return statement.

When I run the function with the return statement I get a one word output which is one of the following: 'fizz' 'buzz' or 'fizzbuzz', but when I run the function using console.log the output is counting to the limit and saying 'fizz' 'buzz' or 'fizzbuzz' whenever it comes across a multiple of 3, 5 or both/ why is this so?

```
input = fizzBuzz(100)
console.log(input)

function fizzBuzz(limit){
    for (let i = 0; i <= limit; ++i)
    if (i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0) 
    console.log('fizzbuzz')
    else if (i % 3 === 0)
    console.log('fizz')
    else if (i % 5 === 0)
    console.log('buzz')
    else console.log(i)
}


input = fizzBuzz(100)
console.log(input)

function fizzBuzz(limit){
    for (let i = 0; i <= limit; ++i) {
        if (i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0)
            return 'fizzbuzz'
        else if (i % 3 === 0)
            return 'fizz'
        else if (i % 5 === 0)
            return 'buzz'
        else return i
    }
}
```

I think it is because the return statement stops the function from executing anything further but I am not sure, still new and self teaching!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`return` evaluates its argument (if supplied) and ends the execution of the containing function immediately.

`console.log` evaluates its argument and prints it, continuing the execution of the function it's called from.

So in your example with `return`, the fact that you're in a for-loop that goes `limit` times doesn't matter, because you'll only go through it once and `return` from `fizzBuzz`.

Putting it all together with another example:

```
function print_dog() {
  console.log('dog');
  return;
  console.log('cat');
}
```

If you then call `print_dog()`, you'll see the output `dog`, but you won't see the output `cat`, because `return` ends execution of `print_dog` before it can get to `console.log('cat');`

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in stating that it is because the return statement exits the function.

This is also the case in python,java, and many other languages.

Cheers!

Comment: How can you say that this is the only difference? If a method returns something, the returned value can be used later on. If a method prints something on the console, there is no way to use the printed value anywhere else

Comment: Technically program output can be used elsewhere, such as in a bash pipe or output redirect. That being said, you're right - there is definitely a difference between returns and prints.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what each different function does:

```
function fizzBuzz(limit) {
    for (let i = 0; i <= limit; ++i)
        if (i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0)
            console.log('fizzbuzz')
        else if (i % 3 === 0)
            console.log('fizz')
        else if (i % 5 === 0)
            console.log('buzz')
        else console.log(i)
}
```

This iterates through to `limit`, and `console.log`s the FizzBuzz test result each time.

```
function fizzBuzz(limit){
    for (let i = 0; i <= limit; ++i) {
        if (i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0)
            return 'fizzbuzz'
        else if (i % 3 === 0)
            return 'fizz'
        else if (i % 5 === 0)
            return 'buzz'
        else return i
    }
}
```

This iterates through to `limit`, and returns a single value from the function - the result of the FizzBuzz test on the first iteration.

So essentially, one function logs all the FizzBuzz results to the console, and the other returns one FizzBuzz result, which you are logging to the console manually.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are thinking on the correct lines.

A return statement in a function will return a value and stop further execution. Where as Console.log() is a side effect producing function that will print the arguments supplied to it in the console.

Having a console.log() inside a function is like calling a function within a function.